# Uploading file to Google Drive using resumable API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have  a quite large file that I am trying to upload to google drive using the API. I am trying to do it with a sample image for learning purposes. Uploading the image as a multiplart upload or a single file upload works without hesitation, but the moment I try to do it using the resumable upload endpoint, the code gives me a error as:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badContent",
    "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/jpeg"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unsupported content with type: image/jpeg"
 }
}
```

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
import requests
import os
filesize = os.path.getsize('./photo.jpeg')
print("File size is: ", filesize)

headers = {"Authorization" : "Bearer "+"<MY API KEY HERE>",
        "Content-Length": str(filesize),
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}
params = {
        "name": "sample.png",
        "parents": ['1CxrbEfy5y3ZyBVF6k2IFIuOk_Z0wjZAo']
        }
files  = {
        'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(params), 'image/jpeg'),
        'file': open('./photo.jpeg', 'rb')
        }

r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers = headers,
        files = files
        )
print(r.text)
```

Please help.

Comment: If I modify the POST url as `"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",`, then it works  as intended. ``` {
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1oorSysJXM0y14LrEr-GL2_rCq4pC3kfH",
 "name": "Untitled",
 "mimeType": "application/json"
} ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to upload an image file of `photo.jpeg` using the resumable upload.
- You want to achieve this using `requests` with python.
- Your access token can upload a file to Google Drive.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script,

  - `params` is not used.
  - The file is directly send to `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`.
  - `"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"` is used in the request headers. By this, the error occurs.
  - You try to upload `'./photo.jpeg'`. But you try to set the filename as `sample.png`.
- In order to upload a file with the resumable upload, at first, it is required to retrieve `location` which is the URL for uploading the file. This is included in the response headers. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)
- After `location` was retrieved, the data can be uploaded to the endpoint of `location`.

#### Sample script:

In the following sample script, an image (`image/jpeg`) is uploaded with the resumable upload. In this case, as a simple test, the file is uploaded by one chunk. Before you use this, please set the variables of `access_token`, `filename`

```
import json
import os
import requests

access_token = '###'  # Please set your access token.
filename = './photo.jpeg'  # Please set the filename with path.

filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
print("File size is: ", filesize)

# 1. Retrieve session for resumable upload.
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
params = {
    "name": "sample.jpeg",
    "parents": ['1CxrbEfy5y3ZyBVF6k2IFIuOk_Z0wjZAo'],
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(params)
)
location = r.headers['Location']

# 2. Upload the file.
headers = {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)}
r = requests.put(location, headers=headers, data=open(filename, 'rb'))
print(r.text)
```

- Please also confirm whether the parent ID of `1CxrbEfy5y3ZyBVF6k2IFIuOk_Z0wjZAo` is correct, again.

#### Reference:

- [Perform a resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works! I am going through each part now :)

Comment: @Sandesh Bhusal Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.