# How to upload and delete files with google drive API using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a image to google drive using requests, but it's not working because the requests keep giving me a status 401 (wrong credentials). I am using the access token that was given to me, so I don't know what is going on.

There's my code:

```
tokendrive = TOKEN_DRIVE
url = "site_url"
myid = MY_ID
subid = MY_SUB_ID
r = requests.get(url)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokendrive} 
para = {"name": submission.id + ".png",
        "parents": [myid]}
files = {"data": ("metadata", json.dumps(para), "application/json; charset=UTF-8"),
         "file": io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)}
response = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files",headers=headers,files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: this might help you get the auth working https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114435/4243927 answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to upload a file to Google Drive.
- You want to delete a file on Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using `request` module of python.
- From your endpoint, you want to use Drive API v3.
- Your access token can be used for uploading and deleting the file using Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- If your access token can be used for uploading a file to Google Drive, it is required to modify the script for using the access token. In this case, please modify `Token` to `Bearer`. I thought that the reason of your error might be due to this.
- When Drive API v3 is used, the property of `parents` is `"parents": [myid]`. And in the current stage, please use one folder ID here.
- In the case of Drive API v3, the filename can be given with `name` instead of `title`. `title` is used for Drive API v2.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

This modified script uploads a file of to Google Drive. Before you use this script, please confirm the variables you want to use, again.

```
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {tokendrive}'} # or 'Bearer ' + tokendrive
para = {
    "name": "image_url.jpg",
    "parents": [myid]
}
files = {
    "data": ("metadata", json.dumps(para), "application/json; charset=UTF-8"),
    "file": io.BytesIO(requests.get(submission.url).content)
}
response = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files
)
print(response.text)
```

- In this script, the following value is returned.

  ```
    {
     "kind": "drive#file",
     "id": "###",
     "name": "image_url.jpg",
     "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
    }
  ```
- In this modified script, the maximum file size for uploading is 5 MB. When you want to upload a file over 5 MB, please use resumable upload. In that case, I think that this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60528771/7108653)

#### Sample script:

This sample script deletes a file on Google Drive.

```
fileId = '###' # Please set the file ID you want to delete.
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {tokendrive}'} # or 'Bearer ' + tokendrive
response = requests.delete(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId,
    headers=headers,
)
print(response.text)
```

- In this case, no value is returned. This is the current specification.
- **IMPORTANT**: This script completely deletes the file of `fileId`. So please be careful this. I would like to recommend to test using a sample file.

#### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `I still have the same problem with authentication`, in that case, your access token might not be used for uploading a file. So can you confirm it again? And also, can you add your current script for replicating your issue? If you can do it, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Gevezo And also, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Maybe I need more information about the specific folder ?`. If you tested my 1st sample script and you cannot understand about `myid`, how about using `root` as `myid` or removing `"parents": [myid]`? By this, the uploaded file is put to the root folder. By this, when your access token can be used for uploading a file, the script works.

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying and adding your current script. When I saw your script, I noticed an important modification point. In your script, `headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + tokendrive}` is used as the header. If `tokendrive` is the access token, please add a space like 'Bearer '. Your script is `'Bearer'`. I thought that this is the reason of your issue. So your modified script becomes `headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokendrive}`. By this modification, please test it again.

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional new 2 questions, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your 2nd question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `that means the file is too large ?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? About your 3rd question, it's yes.

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd and 3rd questions were resolved. And also, I apologize for the inconvenience. About your 4th question, I would like to support you. But I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide your current script and the sample PNG file for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your current goal? By the way, your current goal was changed from your 1st question?

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. Unfortunately, when I tested my sample script for uploading a PNG file, no error occurs. I deeply apologize for this situation. So in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample PNG file for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, about `the .png file is not valid (it does not open as an image)`, can you also provide the file?

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying and adding the sample PNG files. When I saw your files, the file size of all files is `0`. I think that this is the reason of your issue. I apologize for this situation. In my environment. when the PNG file which has the correct PNG data is uploaded using my sample script, I can confirm that the PNG file can be seen. Can you confirm this again?

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I thought that your sample PNG files are files you want to upload. From your replying, I understood those are the uploaded files.When you had uploaded those files from several URLs, I think that the reason of your issue is due to the URLs. In order to check whether the script correctly works, can you test the following situation?

Comment: @Gevezo For example, using my sample script, when the URL of `io.BytesIO(requests.get(submission.url).content)` is `https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png` which is the logo of Stackoverflow, I can confirm that the correct image can be uploaded. When you test this and the same result that the file has no data size occurs, I think that your script has an issue. At that time, can you provide your script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: http://collabedit.com/u98t3, I'm using this exact script and having the same problem, maybe I'm  writing something wrong ?

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I saw your current script, I confirmed that you don't correctly use my proposed script. In your situation, the file is uploaded with `multipart/form-data`. In this case, the endpoint is `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart`. But you are using `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files` as the endpoint. This is the reason of your issue. I think that your issue is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Please modify the endpoint and test it again.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This solved the problem, and again, thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Gevezo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.